# Differentiate between optional and mandatory in Pythons argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I am a bit confused with `argparse` but using it for years. Let's see this example:

```
$ ./argpars_debug.py foo --help
usage: argpars_debug.py [-h] [-d] [--version] input

positional arguments:
  input

options:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  -d, --debug
  --version    show program's version number and exit
```

### Problem

The `input` argument is mandatory. But using `--version` without `input` is possible.

```
$ ./argpars_debug.py --version
0.1.2
```

But using `--debug` without `input` is not possible:

```
$ ./argpars_debug.py --debug
usage: argpars_debug.py [-h] [-d] [--version] input
argpars_debug.py: error: the following arguments are required: input
```

### My Goal

I would like to use `--debug` with and without `input`.

```
$ ./argpars_debug.py --debug
$ ./argpars_debug.py foo --debug
```

I can do this with `--version`. But I don't understand how I can modify this behavior.

### The minimal working example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import sys

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('input', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--debug', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('--version', action='version', version='0.1.2')

    return parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print(f'{sys.argv=}')
```

Comment: In argparse the "version" is a special action type and it requires extra argument version in add_argument to return the version and program exits after that. For action 'store_true/false' it will store the value and program will continue but then it will see that input is required but not provided.

Comment: `action='version'` is like 'help'.  It prints its message and exits the program. What's supposed to happen with 'debug'?  Can you debug without the 'input' value?

Comment: `--debug` without any further input is supposed to give diagnostic output (e.g. versions of dependencies, OS version, etc) only. If there is no argparse specific solution I think I have to add a new switch like `--diagnostics`.

Comment: Probably better to have a separate switch, rather than having `--debug` do different things based on presence of other arguments.

Comment: Write a custom Action subclass modeled on the help or version classes.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [Argparse optional positional arguments?](/q/4480075/4518341) Otherwise, how do you want the script to work if `--debug` is not provided?

Comment: In theory you could write an Action class that checks the `namespace` for a (nondefault) `input` attribute, and then decide whether to set a `debug` attribute, or print the debug info and do the system exit.  But you need to look at the `argparse.py` code to understand how to write such a class.  In general writing `Action` classes that check values across attributes is extra work, and probably not worth it.  Simply making a flagged '--input' argument may be simpler.  Try to imagine what's least confusing to your end user(s).

Comment: *"I would like to use --debug with and without input."*  -->That means "input" is optional, not mandatory.